# Making an input field required from WP's perspective

Tags: forms

Submitting a post comment without message leads to a white page with a clean WP error message "ERROR: please type a comment."

Is it possible to achieve the same thing for input fields from a custom form? For instance, I've got my own custom contact page template containing a number of input fields, some of them I want to make required. How to get the same WP error message when those haven't been filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe yo are looking for [**`wp_die`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die) which will Kill WordPress execution and display HTML message with error message.

But the codex says:

> It is not recommended to call this function very often and try to handle as many errors as possible silently.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bainternet. I think "very often" is too vague though, does calling it for missing fields in contact form fall into the "very often" category?

Comment: not really IMHO